# How to group variables and do barplot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want to compare the counts or relative frequencies of the variables using R barplot.

This is a sample dataframe

```
       Q7B1 Q7A2 Q7B2 Q7A3 Q7B3
    1    NA    2   NA    1    2
    2    NA    2   NA    1    2
    3     2    2   NA    1    2
    4     2    2   NA    1    2
    5    NA    2   NA    1    2
    6    NA    2   NA    2   NA
    7     2    2   NA    1    2
    8    NA    2   NA    2   NA
    9    NA    2   NA    2   NA
    10    2    2   NA    1    2
```

I would like to create a barplot where each variable (Q7B1, Q7B2, Q7B3, ....,Q7B8) represents a bar. Each variable has values (1,2,3) The height of the bar would represent the count or the relative frequency of the value "2" of each variable. How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data frame is named `dat`, you can do:

```
barplot(colSums(dat == 2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

[image]

To obtain a plot with relative frequencies, you can use the following command:

```
barplot(colSums(dat == 2, na.rm = TRUE) / nrow(dat))
```

Comment: Hi Sven! Thank you for this! for the relative frequencies, it seems the relative frequencies are far too small. I change it to colSums instead of colMeans and multiply it to 100 to get the percentage. It seems to be correct. By the way, how did you add the variable label in the displayed graph? my graph dont have the variable label.

Comment: @dixi Right, `colSums` is correct. Variable names are returned by `colSums`. These are the column names of the data frame (or matrix)  `dat`.

Answer (score 0):

First to you want to get the frequency of 2 in each column:

```
freqs <- apply(dataframe, 2, function(column) { 
    length(which(column == 2))/nrow(dataframe) 
})
names(freqs) <- names(dataframe) # may be redundant
```

Then you can simply barplot it:

```
barplot(freqs)
```

Comment: Hi @Manetheran! Do I need to replace the variable "column" to each of my variable name? (e.g. Q7B1 etc) I cant seem to make this work.